# Native crash at getResources().getStringArray

Tags: android

Native crash at `getResources().getStringArray` on some devices such as Samsung On7 Pro and Samsung Galaxy J8. On other devices same code is working fine. I am not able to figure out what is wrong. Below is the stack trace of crash.

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000004b95c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  #01  pc 000000000001a733  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+54)
  #02  pc 0000000000337da3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+230)
  #03  pc 0000000000338433  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+10)
  #04  pc 00000000003efaad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+456)
  #05  pc 00000000002300df  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1262)
  #06  pc 000000000023033b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+66)
  #07  pc 000000000028b3f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI9NewStringEP7_JNIEnvPKti+590)
  #08  pc 00000000000ea39d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7androidL51android_content_AssetManager_getArrayStringResourceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+244)
  #09  pc 0000000000a51567  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringInfo [DEDUPED]+78)
  #10  pc 0000000000a596ff  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray+86)
  #11  pc 00000000003dd1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #12  pc 00000000003e1755  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
  #13  pc 00000000000ac0e1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+140)
  #14  pc 00000000001f1cf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+238)
  #15  pc 00000000001ed2a3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+574)
  #16  pc 00000000003c9691  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+504)
  #17  pc 00000000003d3214  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #18  pc 00000000001d4825  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #19  pc 00000000001d9ba7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+142)
  #20  pc 00000000001ed28d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+552)
  #21  pc 00000000003c7f71  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+360)
  #22  pc 00000000003cf594  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
  #23  pc 00000000001d4825  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+340)
  #24  pc 00000000001d9af5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+92)
  #25  pc 00000000003bd7f5  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+960)
  #26  pc 00000000003e0fa1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
  #27  pc 00000000007eebc5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate+108)
  #28  pc 0000000000712309  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity+1936)
  #29  pc 000000000070a21b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity+298)
  #30  pc 00000000006fe84f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11+62)
  #31  pc 00000000006fb5c5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+8676)
  #32  pc 0000000000e94cfb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+138)
  #33  pc 0000000000ee3243  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1066)
  #34  pc 000000000071036d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+932)
  #35  pc 00000000003dd1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #36  pc 00000000003e185b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+226)
  #37  pc 00000000000ac10b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+182)
  #38  pc 000000000033215d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
  #39  pc 00000000003336a3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12InvokeMethodERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectS4_S4_j+946)
  #40  pc 00000000002e1475  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Method_invokeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_S3_+40)
  #41  pc 0000000000250bdf  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+110)
  #42  pc 000000000162b055  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+124)
  #43  pc 000000000162f245  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+3076)
  #44  pc 00000000003dd1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #45  pc 00000000003e185b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+226)
  #46  pc 00000000000ac10b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+182)
  #47  pc 000000000033215d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+52)
  #48  pc 0000000000331f69  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+296)
  #49  pc 0000000000285c83  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+430)
  #50  pc 00000000000a0f41  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv20CallStaticVoidMethodEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz+36)
  #51  pc 00000000000a284b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+466)
  #52  pc 0000000000003215  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+1180)
  #53  pc 0000000000017e89  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
  #54  pc 0000000000002ca0  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start+96)
```

Comment: We cannot help you so much without any piece of code (the Asset Array for example) or other things. Try to create a tiny and easy version of that array and check if that Array could contain something that in a different Language/Locale Settings could be wrong interpreted (like a special chars, wrong charset, etc...)